# how to extract a variable from divisions?

Tags: calculus

I got a physics formula r_ws(p,T)
I'm looking to reverse it, to get  T(r_ws, p) ?

However, I don't know where should I start.

```
e_ws = 6.107 * 10^(7.5*T/(237.3+T))
r_ws = 0.622*e_ws/(p-e_ws)
```

Comment: Solve for $e$, then solve for $T$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use the following formula
$$
  y = \frac{x}{x+a} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x(y-1) = -ay \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x = -\frac{ay}{y-1}
$$